# How to retrieve a supplemental table from oracle responsys api?

Tags: oracle, responsys

According to the Responsys documentation, I can only pull all supplemental tables.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/responsys-develop/API/REST/api-v1.3-suppData-get.htm

What would my endpoint be if I just wanted to pull one table instead of all of them?

Using this does work to pull them all:

/rest/api/v1.3/suppData

I am able to see the folderName and objectName for the table I want to pull, but when I plug them into this url, I get the 404 error.

/rest/api/v1.3/folder/{folderName}/suppData/{suppTableName}

I know the table exists because it shows up when I call all the supplemental tables.

What do I do? Please HELP :)